# Python recursive function that prints a pattern

Tags: python, recursion

Writing a recursive function that only takes ints that are a power of 2, and should print this pattern:

```
>>> pattern(1)
1
>>> pattern(2)
112
>>> pattern(4)
1121124
>>> pattern(8)
112112411211248
```

I have the following:

```
def pattern(n):
    if n == 1:
        print(1)
    else:
        pattern(n-1)
        print(n,end='')
        pattern(n-1)
```

The pattern is outputting an incorrect format...I'm not sure how to phrase the else statement above.

the output I get is:

```
>>> pattern(1)
1
>>> pattern(2)
1
2
1
```

Comment: So what's wrong with it? Is it giving you an error? What's up

Comment: I see you have some code. That is a good start. What is the problem with your code? Does it do something you do not expect? Can you post the output of your program or describe what the problem is?

Comment: "The pattern is outputting the correct format...I'm not sure how to phrase it" Why not just literally post the output?

Comment: Sure I'll post the output.....I'm not sure how to phrase the recursive function..

Comment: Swap the `print(n,end='')` with the 2nd `pattern(n-1)`.

Comment: This seems more like something you can just debug yourself... It's working just as you told it to do. If it's not working the way you want then that's up to your and only a matter of debugging and repairing it before it gets to the expected result

Comment: If you can clearly define what your function is supposed to do, you'll have solved your problem.  Things to think about: How could you get a recursive function to produce that output?  Should it print more than one line (as yours prints quite a few lines right now)? Is there a way to limit it to only printing one line?  Is n-1 the thing you should pass into your function?  Is there a reason this function is expected to only work on powers of 2?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, split the pattern-making and printing into two methods.
pattern(n) should return a string, then just call print once on pattern(n).

Secondly, take a closer look at what your pattern looks like:

pattern(2) = pattern(1) + pattern(1) + 2
pattern(4) = pattern(2) + pattern(2) + 4
pattern(8) = pattern(4) + pattern(4) + 8

or more general:
pattern(n) = pattern(n/2) + pattern(n/2) + n

Finally, make sure you can only call pattern() on a power of 2, otherwise you're going to have a bad time.